# Scrapy spider works locally, but not on scrapinghub

Tags: python, openssl, scrapy, twisted

I'm using a scrapy spider to send 2 POST requests to a site.
On my local computer it works, and I get 2 responses.

But on Scrapy Cloud ([scrapinghub.com](https://app.scrapinghub.com)) I get same error for each request:

> [scrapy.core.scraper] Error downloading https://baca.ii.uj.edu.pl/p12018/testerka_gwt/problems>:
>   twisted.python.failure.Failure OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines',
>   'SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO', 'tlsv1 alert internal error')]>]

The site's certificate has expired, and I think this is causing the problems. But scrapy docs say that site certificate is by default not checked, so I don't know.

My spider code:

```
class resultsTest(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "results"

    custom_settings = {
        'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': False,
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        firstAss = 4 #first assignment
        lastAss = 5 #last assignment
        url = 'https://baca.ii.uj.edu.pl/p12018/testerka_gwt/problems'
        bodyBeginning = '7|0|5|https://baca.ii.uj.edu.pl/p12018/testerka_gwt/|548F7E6329FFDEC9688CE48426651141|testerka.gwt.client.problems.ProblemsService|getProblemStatistic|I|1|2|3|4|1|5|'
        headers = {
                "Content-Type": "text/x-gwt-rpc; charset=UTF-8",
                "X-GWT-Module-Base": "https://baca.ii.uj.edu.pl/p12018/testerka_gwt/",
                "X-GWT-Permutation": "5A4AE95C27260DF45F17F9BF027335F6",
                }

        for num in range(firstAss, lastAss + 1):
            body = bodyBeginning + str(num) + "|" 
            yield scrapy.Request(
                    url,
                    method = "POST",
                    headers = headers,
                    body = body)

    def parse(self, response):
        yield response.body_as_unicode()
```